# Derive $a^x$ using infinitesimal notation

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

Consider $f(x) = a^x$. It holds that $$f'
(x)\mathrm dx = f(x + \mathrm dx) - f(x)$$
using infinitesimal notation. Plugging all in, we get that $$f'(x)\mathrm dx = a^{x + \mathrm dx} - a^{x}.$$
Is it true that $a^{x+\mathrm dx} - a^x = a^{x}(a^{\mathrm dx} - 1)$ using algebra? And if yes, how can I justify that $a^{\mathrm dx} - 1 = \log(a)$? This should hold since $f'(x) = a^x\log(a)$ using the rgular $\epsilon$-$\delta$ derivative.

Comment: I'd recommend refraining from using differential forms (the things like dx that you call infinitesimals) because they aren't numbers that you can conventionally add.

Comment: Actually you need to show $(a^{dx}-1)/dx=ln(a)$ as $dx$ goes to $0$.

Comment: I agree with Khallil but  we can say that $a^t \approx 1 + ln(a)t$ for small $t$ and you can procedue further.